# Split string on a number, preserving the number

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a string which will always be at least a number, but can also contain letters before and/or after the number:

```
"4"
"Section 2"
"4 Section"
"Section 5 Aisle"
```

I need to split the string like this:

```
"4" becomes "4"
"Section 2" becomes "Section ","2"
"4 Aisle" becomes "4"," Aisle"
"Section 5 Aisle" becomes "Section ","5"," Aisle"
```

How can I do this with Ruby 1.9.2?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`String#split` will [keep any groups](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M001165) from the delimiter regexp in the result array.

```
parts = whole.split(/(\d+)/)
```

Answer (score 2):

In case you didn't really want the whitespace in the separators, and you did want to have a consistent handle on the before/after, use this:

```
test = [
  "4",
  "Section 2",
  "4 Section",
  "Section 5 Aisle",
]

require 'pp'
pp test.map{ |str| str.split(/\s*(\d+)\s*/,-1) }
#=> [["", "4", ""],
#=>  ["Section", "2", ""],
#=>  ["", "4", "Section"],
#=>  ["Section", "5", "Aisle"]]
```

Thus you could always do:

```
prefix, digits, suffix = str.split(/\s*(\d+)\s*/,-1)
if prefix.empty?
  ...
end
```

...instead of testing the length of your matches or some such.